# Layout run when using real device

Tags: android, xml, listview

There has a `listView` and `imageView`,`text` and `button` in **Activity A**. If **listView.size** is equal to 0, it will display the `image`,`text` and `button` , if not equal to 0, it will display the `listView`.

Do I need to have a seperate layout for this ? One for `imageView`,`text` and `button` and another for `listView` ?

Currently I using the same layout but when I use my real device to run, the design of `image`,`text` and `button` are slightly run.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView

        android:src="@mipmap/data"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Data"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:paddingTop="160dp"
        android:textColor="@color/honey_dew2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/NoData"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Data"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />



    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Android Studio**

[image]

**Real device** (display image, text and button only since listView.size is equal to 0)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your layout like this

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@mipmap/data"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Data"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Then in your code do this check:

```
if(yourList.length() != 0){
   mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
   mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}else{
   mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
   mButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout`

Comment: @Tony what is this link, where is the quesiton

Comment: Here the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462471/spinner-data-duplicated-when-list-is-clicked) Thanks sir

Comment: ping me at the chat please

Answer (score 1):

In your XML file you have hard coded all the values not properly utilizing the relativelayout properties which is causing you the problem. As all the device have different density pixels so rendering is effected so u should avoid hard coded as much as possible.

try this code:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView

        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No Data"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/NoData"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Data"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NoData"/>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />



    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How to make the `NoData` text display below the image?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this with a variable using visibility of the View class.

In your java code:

```
 mTextview.setVisibility(View.GONE); //or View.INVISIBLE
```

Set your defaults to come up in the XML using:

```
<View android:id="@+id/myView" android:visibility="gone" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many reasons is that your real device and your design screen in android studio are different (size, dpi,...). You should check both of them. Besides, you have put imageView width and height is 330dp, too big for some device.

Your ImageView, TextView and Button are all layout_gravity="center" in one RelativeLayout, so they are overlap.