# Spinner data duplicated when list is clicked

Tags: java, android, json, listview, spinner

In Activity B there has a `spinner` where the data were get from `MySQL` (Table location).

**Activity B**

```
private ArrayList<String> froms;
private JSONArray resultFrom;

public void addItemsOnFrom() {

    travelFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.travelFrom);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Configs.FROM_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        resultFrom = j.getJSONArray(Configs.JSON_ARRAY);

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getFrom(resultFrom);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getFrom(JSONArray j) {
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            froms.add(json.getString(Configs.TAG_LOCATION));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
    travelFrom.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Add_Details_Information.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, froms));
}
```

When save `button` is clicked, it will return the selected value(OFFICE) to Activity A `listView`. And in Activity A, when the list is pressed, it will intent to Activity B. In this time, the spinner in Activity B will display the selected item first(OFFICE).

```
**Table location**  // table location has 2 data
NONE 
OFFICE
```

Assume OFFICE is selected in B. When list is clicked, I want OFFICE display first in `spinner` B.

Code in **Activity B** for display OFFICE first.

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
{ 
    final String from = getIntent().getStringExtra("from");
    selectedItemFrom(from);
}
```

---

```
public void selectedItemFrom(final String value)// display  OFFICE first
{
    travelFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.travelFrom);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Configs.FROM_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(Configs.JSON_ARRAY);

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getFrom(result, value);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getFrom(JSONArray j, String value) {
    int position = 0;
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            froms.add(json.getString(Configs.TAG_LOCATION));
            if (froms.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {

                position = i;
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),position+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    travelFrom.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Add_Details_Information.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, froms));
    travelFrom.setSelection(position);
}
```

The OFFICE can display first, but the problem is when I checked the spinner B, it shows `NONE,OFFICE,NONE OFFICE` ..Why the spinner data will get duplicated ? Thanks

I think problem is in this line  `travelFrom.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Add_Details_Information.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, froms));`...But how to solve??? Anyone?

And sometimes the spinner will display the selected item first but sometimes it will not...What are the better way to write?

**Edit**

```
{"result":[{"name":"NONE"},{"name":"OFFICE"}]}
```

I put forms.clear in beginning of both getFrom method now. But the problem is when I select NONE and return to A, then goes to B again,the spinner now has NONE only...

Comment: just print the size of forms inside getFrom(JSONArray j,String value). and clear the data beforing adding to the list forms.clear();

Comment: @SreeReddyMenon I add  `Log.e("SIZE",froms.size()+"");` inside try block but log did not display

Comment: okey. now do the same thing inside catch. is it printing system.err..kind of stuff.?

Comment: @SreeReddyMenon no. The problem is I use Toast to display the size, but no Toast is showing.

Comment: @SreeReddyMenon Can  you teach me the second method ? clear list

Comment: please debug yourself. i think here it is repeating i think.  i am not sure.  try log  the form value inside if condition.. just log everything. you will get.   if (froms.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {

                        position = i;
                        
                        break;
                    }

Comment: Please add to your question what the JSON response looks like

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry sir..how to show the JSON response? which line

Comment: ... I don't know how to explain this... Whatever this variable equals, go to that address on your computer in the browser `Configs.FROM_URL`. Copy all the content, then paste it into an edit to your question, not the comments. I also didn't say *line*

Comment: @cricket_007 this is what I get when I paste the url to browser. The spinner in the data duplicated but in the table location, it still has two data only

Comment: Put `froms.clear()` at the beiginning of both `getFrom()` methods. And I recommend using `JsonObjectRequest` instead of StringRequest since you are expecting JSON responses

Comment: do you fixed it? @AI.

Comment: @cricket_007  If I select `OFFICE`, then return to A, then B again. I see `NONE` and `OFFICE` in spinner. That's fine. If I select `NONE`, then return to to then B again, the spinner has `NONE` only

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan no, fixing...

Comment: Why is there a break statement inside the loop. That will exit that loop as soon as you hit the first matching element, thus stopping anymore elements to be added to `froms`

Comment: @cricket_007 what is the correct way ?

Comment: remove that if statement entirely and do `position = froms.indexOf(value)`

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks you sir it works, but do you have any idea why sometimes it will display the selected item first but sometimes not?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do.... All I can see is a JSON object being loaded into a Spinner, then you want to set the position of the correct string. ... If that is all you want to do, this answer looks like what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/4228121/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 yes sir, I want the selected item display in spinner first when listView in A is clicked. Sometimes it works but sometimes not. And I have used that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like this.

This activity will expect a Intent with the key `"from"` that is set to either `"NONE"` or `"OFFICE"`. If the intent does not have the data, then it will default to whatever was inserted into the Spinner first.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner travelFrom;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mSpinnerAdapter;
    private List<String> mSpinnerData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String from = null;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            from = extras.getString("from");
        }

        setupFromSpinner(from);
    }

    private void setupFromSpinner(final String value) {
        travelFrom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.travelFrom);
        mSpinnerData = new ArrayList<String>();
        mSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mSpinnerData);
        mSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        travelFrom.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);

        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Configs.FROM_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        mSpinnerData.clear();
                        try {
                            JSONArray resultFrom = response.getJSONArray("result");
                            for (int i = 0; i < resultFrom.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject fromObj = resultFrom.getJSONObject(i);
                                String name = fromObj.getString("name");
                                mSpinnerData.add(name);
                            }
                            mSpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        if (value != null) {
                            int position = mSpinnerAdapter.getPosition(value);
                            travelFrom.setSelection(position);
                        } else {
                            travelFrom.setSelection(0);
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }
        );

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(req);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add froms.clear() to this piece of code;

```
private void getFrom(JSONArray j) {
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    froms.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            froms.add(json.getString(Configs.TAG_LOCATION));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
    travelFrom.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Add_Details_Information.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, froms));
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea why sometimes it will display the selected item first but sometimes not?

Comment: seems like you set the adapter twice, for no reason. You also do this after you find the location of your value, so maybe you set a different adapter with a different index of the value  you re choosing. You should really call this "travelFrom.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Add_Details_Information.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, froms));" only once at initialization

Comment: @cricket answer worked as the data in `spinner` will not duplicated now

Comment: simple clear your arraylist before getting responce data tq u marcin d